# How to avoid Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null with Meteor?

Tags: meteor

When using 3rd party libraries like UserVoice with Meteor how do you avoid a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null` error based on load order?

I put this file in `client/uservoice.js`

```
// Include the UserVoice JavaScript SDK (only needed once on a page)
UserVoice=window.UserVoice||[];(function(){var uv=document.createElement('script');uv.type='text/javascript';uv.async=true;uv.src='//widget.uservoice.com/GSl7xKyRNrN4iiGY3j53hA.js';var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(uv,s)})();

//
// UserVoice Javascript SDK developer documentation:
// https://www.uservoice.com/o/javascript-sdk
//

// Set colors
UserVoice.push(['set', {
  accent_color: '#448dd6',
  trigger_color: 'white',
  trigger_background_color: 'rgba(46, 49, 51, 0.6)'
}]);

// Identify the user and pass traits
// To enable, replace sample data with actual user traits and uncomment the line
UserVoice.push(['identify', {
  //email:      'john.doe@example.com', // User’s email address
  //name:       'John Doe', // User’s real name
  //created_at: 1364406966, // Unix timestamp for the date the user signed up
  //id:         123, // Optional: Unique id of the user (if set, this should not change)
  //type:       'Owner', // Optional: segment your users by type
  //account: {
  //  id:           123, // Optional: associate multiple users with a single account
  //  name:         'Acme, Co.', // Account name
  //  created_at:   1364406966, // Unix timestamp for the date the account was created
  //  monthly_rate: 9.99, // Decimal; monthly rate of the account
  //  ltv:          1495.00, // Decimal; lifetime value of the account
  //  plan:         'Enhanced' // Plan name for the account
  //}
}]);

// Add default trigger to the bottom-right corner of the window:
UserVoice.push(['addTrigger', { mode: 'contact', trigger_position: 'bottom-right' }]);

// Or, use your own custom trigger:
//UserVoice.push(['addTrigger', '#id', { mode: 'contact' }]);

// Autoprompt for Satisfaction and SmartVote (only displayed under certain conditions)
UserVoice.push(['autoprompt', {}]);
```

Comment: Start by putting all this code in `Meteor.startup`. Does the problem persist after you do?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @hubert for the tip.

Wrapping it in `Meteor.startup` did the trick.

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
// Include the UserVoice JavaScript SDK (only needed once on a page)
  UserVoice=window.UserVoice||[];(function(){var uv=document.createElement('script');uv.type='text/javascript';uv.async=true;uv.src='//widget.uservoice.com/GSl7xKyRNrN4iiGY3j53hA.js';var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(uv,s)})();

  //
  // UserVoice Javascript SDK developer documentation:
  // https://www.uservoice.com/o/javascript-sdk
  //

  // Set colors
  UserVoice.push(['set', {
    accent_color: '#448dd6',
    trigger_color: 'white',
    trigger_background_color: 'rgba(46, 49, 51, 0.6)'
  }]);

  // Identify the user and pass traits
  // To enable, replace sample data with actual user traits and uncomment the line
  UserVoice.push(['identify', {
    //email:      'john.doe@example.com', // User’s email address
    //name:       'John Doe', // User’s real name
    //created_at: 1364406966, // Unix timestamp for the date the user signed up
    //id:         123, // Optional: Unique id of the user (if set, this should not change)
    //type:       'Owner', // Optional: segment your users by type
    //account: {
    //  id:           123, // Optional: associate multiple users with a single account
    //  name:         'Acme, Co.', // Account name
    //  created_at:   1364406966, // Unix timestamp for the date the account was created
    //  monthly_rate: 9.99, // Decimal; monthly rate of the account
    //  ltv:          1495.00, // Decimal; lifetime value of the account
    //  plan:         'Enhanced' // Plan name for the account
    //}
  }]);

  // Add default trigger to the bottom-right corner of the window:
  UserVoice.push(['addTrigger', { mode: 'contact', trigger_position: 'bottom-right' }]);

  // Or, use your own custom trigger:
  //UserVoice.push(['addTrigger', '#id', { mode: 'contact' }]);

  // Autoprompt for Satisfaction and SmartVote (only displayed under certain conditions)
  UserVoice.push(['autoprompt', {}]);

});
```